# How to store the array length in a variable in bash scripting language

Tags: 12.04, command-line, bash

I stored some information about the system in an arrays  .. and I tried to store the length of an array in a variable then print the value of the variable on the terminal , but there is no output!

```
#!/bin/bash


###################################################################################

openFilesCount=$(lsof -Fn -u teeba| sort  | uniq | grep /home | wc -l);

openPortsCount=$(lsof -Fn -u teeba| sort  | uniq | grep /home | wc -l);

readingTime=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%T);

usersArr=($(awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 && $1 != "nobody" {print $1}' /etc/passwd) );

pidsArr=($(ps axo pid));

lastIdex=${#usersArr[@]};

###################################################################################

echo "$lastIndex";
```

**Where is the error ?** How to store the array's length in a variable ?

Comment: your syntax looks fine, what is the error showing in terminal?

Comment: @souravc the result must be 3 but i got nothing !!!!

Comment: check the spellings, you stored in `lastIdex` but calling `$lastIndex`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is basically correct. (You don't need any of the `;` there but that's not a problem.)

It seems that somehow your script is not really executed, because:

```
echo ${#nonexistentarray[@]}
```

This will *always* print a number that's 0 (if the array doesn't exist) or higher (if the array or the variable exists).

So in your script, if these two lines are really executed:

```
lastIdex=${#usersArr[@]};
echo "$lastIndex";
```

....... ok... There's a typo there: you're setting the value in `lastIdex` but then printing `lastIndex`... So probably that's your problem.

Comment: No I didn't copy this script from anywhere .. I wrote it using vim editor ... when I typed echo "${#usersArr[@]}" directly i got the right answer which is 3 ... but when i stored the length in a variable then print its value i got nothing !!!!

Comment: @Akari ah.... I just noticed your typo...